# What is the correct way to set param_grid of GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I'm trying out a simple classification of breast_cancer.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import  load_breast_cancer
lbc = load_breast_cancer()
X = pd.DataFrame(lbc.data, columns=lbc.feature_names)
y = pd.Series(lbc.target).to_frame()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_scaled_train=scaler.transform(X_train)
X_scaled_test=scaler.transform(X_test)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

```
param={
    'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'], 
    'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 
    'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
}
grid=GridSearchCV(SVC(), param, cv=5)
grid.fit(X_scaled_train, y_train)
print(grid.best_score_, grid.best_params_)
```

yields,
`0.9788782489740082 {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'linear'}`

```
param2=[
            {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}, 
            {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}
            ]
grid2=GridSearchCV(SVC(), param2, cv=5)
grid2.fit(X_scaled_train, y_train)
print(grid2.best_score_, grid2.best_params_)
```

`0.9788782489740082 {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}`

Except for changing the way to define param_grid, the rest of the code is the same. As you can see, I found different "kernel" with the same "score", "C" and "gamma" values.

Which of above two methods is the right way to set param_grid? Since both are exploring the same hyperparameter sapce(search order is different), I am expecting the same optimal hyperparameter values.

Or is it that rbf and linear change by chance depending on the grid search order because the score is exactly the same in this case?

Answer (score 0):

None is correct. The “linear” kernel does not accept “gamma” as a parameter. Try this

```
param3=[
            {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}, 
            {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}
            ]
```

**Edit**: or rather,  both are approved grid constructs for the function, rather that since the linear kernel can’t digest the gamma parameter, neither will work as intended.